# Location listner in android background service

Tags: java, android

i have search alot to find how to implement the location listener in the Android background service but didnt find any proper answer. i want to run a thread in background service to find throughput and location together. can any body show me by writing small piece of code that can find these values.( a tested one). 
thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 3):

I've used "little-Fluffy-location" and it's great!

I can hardly feel the battery consumption, and it was easy to use.

http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Comment: buddy can u tell me how can i use this library

Comment: I got pretty good results using this library.
There is a clear explanation how to use this library on the link I gave.